# Show that $f(x)= e^{-1/x} \sin e^{1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$ is continuous at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

$$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      e^{-1/x} \sin e^{1/x}  & x\in (0,\infty) \\
      0 & x=0 
   \end{cases}
$$

How do I show this function is continuous at $0$? So far, I have determined that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$$ but  $$\lim_{x \to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} \sin e^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ diverges. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $sin(\cdots)$ is bounded and $exp(-\frac{1}{x})$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(g(x))$ is always bounded, and $\lim_{x \to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} = e^{-\infty}=0$. So, multiplying these yields

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} e^{-\frac{1}{x}} \sin e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 0 \times \mathrm{bounded} = 0 = f(0)$$

So, $f$ is continuous at $x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would note that $x\to 0^+\implies e^{\frac1x}\to+\infty$. Then you have $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(e^{\frac 1x})}{e^{\frac 1x}}=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y}=0$$

Using the substitution $y=e^\frac 1x$. Note the second equality is seen because $|\sin y|\leq 1$, while $y$ is unbounded.